# qmake: how to generate a vcproj (visual studio project) that contains pre-build event?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qmake

I want to generate a MSVC .vcproj file which contains **pre-build event** from qt's .pro file.

I can use **QMAKE_PRE_LINK** | **QMAKE_POST_BUILD** in the .pro file to achieve the similar thing, but it seems qmake does not support **QMAKE_PRE_BUILD**. BTW I am using qt 4.8.4.

One possible solution I found is to modify the qmake code and rebuild it:

http://www.karla9.com/2011/10/03/enable-%E2%80%9Cprebuild%E2%80%9D-step-in-qmake/

but I don't want to rebuild qmake. Is there any other solution? Thx